# How can I cleanly shut down a RabbitTemplate in Spring Rabbit?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I've written a script which uses Spring Rabbit to put a number of messages on a Rabbit queue using [RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html#convertAndSend-java.lang.Object-), and then exits.  However, the Rabbit connection appears to keep the app alive even after the message has been enqueued.  I have not found a way to cleanly tell the Rabbit server to stop after the messages have been enqueued.

The best solution I've been able to come up with is to change my convertAndSend calls to [convertSendAndReceive](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html#convertSendAndReceive-java.lang.Object-) so that I know the message has been successfully enqueued, and then exit using System.exit(0).  I switched to convertSendAndReceive as it appears that convertAndSend happens in a background thread or somesuch, since if I do a System.exit(0) after doing a number of those calls, only the first so many of them will succeed.

Note that merely creating a RabbitTemplate does not cause this behavior; using it via one of the "send" methods does.

The following code illustrates the issue.

```
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;

import static issues.RabbitSettings.*; //Static fields containing my test Rabbit connection info

public class RabbitTemplateShutdownIssue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = createRabbitTemplate();
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(ROUTING_KEY, "Test"); // Or convertSendAndReceive
        // The app never exits
    }

    private static RabbitTemplate createRabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(getConnectionFactory());
        rabbitTemplate.setExchange(EXCHANGE);
        rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    private static ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(HOSTNAME);
        connectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true);
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(VIRTUAL_HOST);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(USERNAME);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        return connectionFactory;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to tell the Rabbit client to shut down, ideally after all messages have been enqueued?

Comment: **Shut down Spring**. You are using Spring Beans with an `ApplicationContext` - this is a PITA to deal with, as you need to shut down things in order so that you don't get exceptions. The simple solution? Do it properly!

Comment: @BoristheSpider There is no Spring container running in my example, so there's no Spring to shut down.

Comment: That is **exactly** my point. (I see now, I meant "without" rather than "with")

Comment: @BoristheSpider Looks like you edited your comment after I started writing my response to it, as the comment I saw and was replying to was simply "Shut down Spring." Your answer makes much more sense with this additional context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you let Spring manage the beans, you can `close()` the application context when you are finished.

The way you have it configured now (no Spring context), you can call `destroy()` on the connection factory and everything will shut down.

Using static methods for stuff like this is an anti-pattern; you'll need to store the factory in a static field so you can destroy the one the template is using.

You need a confirm callback to get confirmation that rabbit received the sends.

Comment: In fairness, the actual script is a Groovy script that does some basic enqueuing of messages and then exits, and not a full-blown production app.  I just wrote my example with the static methods since it seemed like using Java would be more guaranteed to be understood by the Spring audience than Groovy.

Comment: Fair enough. You need a confirm callback on the template to get confirmation that rabbit received the sends.

Comment: The destroy() on the connection factory was exactly what I was looking for.